# Tunneling junction in electromagnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, quantum-tunneling

Why in presence of electromagnetic field hamiltonian,describing 2 systems with tunneling(for example josephson junction )
$$H=H_L+H_R+T(I+I^{\dagger})$$
where $I=c_Lc^{\dagger}_R$ is tunneling operator

should be changed as follows
$$H=H_L+H_R+T(I e^{-i a}+I^{\dagger}e^{ia})$$
where $$a=\int_{L}^{R}\vec{A} d\vec{x}$$
$\vec{A}$-vector potential. For example when we put voltage $V$ to our system,$\vec{A}=-\vec{E}t$ and $a(t)=V t$.

Comment: Could you please provide some more context for your notation? What is I, what is A?

Comment: Also, it looks like this just accounts for probability of tunneling decreasing exponentially with distance. See Griffiths sec 2.6 and 2.7 (finite square well and scattering).

Comment: you can see,that this coefficients became time dependent,unlike in griffiths. Now i think this coefficients should be modified to ensure gauge invariance,but why  in this way?